# Updating constraints programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

Situation is like I have a view with four buttons

[image]

There comes a condition when button with text Search Community should be hidden and width of Options button should get increased

[image]

Using Constraints for the first time in my project, I am not getting how to achieve this. Set of constraints added on both these buttons would be clear from the following two images.

[image]

[image]

Comment: use cgcreckt frame with percentage of uimain screen. no need to add autolayout programmatically.

Comment: You can use IBOutlet with NSLayoutConstraint, and change priority for example.

Comment: When you are 'hiding' your button - do you remove it from the view hierarchy or set its `hidden` property to YES ?

Comment: Search comm. and Options are in a View (except self.view) i mean these buttons are in your newly dragged view?

Comment: @pe60t0 somewhere in the program user can hide search community button. But user still has the option to bring it back.And yes, I am setting  its hidden property to YES.

Comment: @Chetan Prajapati all the buttons are in self.view. This background view(self.view) just has an image view set.

Comment: @Larme please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see with your setup is that you have this constraint between the 2 buttons of equal width. This is true in the first case but when you want to hide one of them, it is not anymore.

So, you will need to rethink your constraints a bit. Maybe instead of the equal width constraint, you could use a static width constraint one the first button(the left one, that you want to hide). Then the second one, will just have a horizontal space constraint to the first one, and a trailing space to the superView.

Then you make an outlet in the VC for the width constraint of the first button and when you want to hide it you do something like this:

```
self.searchButtonWidthConstraint.constant = 0 
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {  () -> Void in
       self.view.layoutIfNeeded() // if you want to animate the constraint change
})
```

Let me know if you have questions. Good luck and hope it works out!

---

**Update**

---

For the landscape use case, you could listen to the orientation change notification, to update the width constraint of the button

```
-(void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    self.searchButtonWidthConstraint.constant = LANDSCAPE_WIDTH
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: {  () -> Void in
           self.view.layoutIfNeeded() // if you want to animate the constraint change
    })
}
```

Comment: yes u r right. Equal width constraint is causing all the trouble. But if i fix the width of first button , as you say, then it does'nt  stretch out accordingly in landscape mode. Plz tell me what else should i try.

Comment: I've update my answer with a suggestion. Let me know if you need more help 

Comment: Thanks a lot! it worked. But I had to code it in 'didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation' as it was'nt responding in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation. As a result it is showing a slight jerk. Is there any way out to smoothen this transition.

Comment: the jerk is because you added it to the `didRotate` instead of `willRotate`. What exactly did not work?

Comment: self.searchBtnWidthConstraint.constant = landscape_width;
where landscape_width = self.btnOnTopOfSearch.frame.size.width/2-8; the frame of the btn on top of searchCommunity is set only after willRotate and not inside the willRotate method.

Comment: ok got the answer. I just had to place my code in 'viewDidLayoutSubviews'   instead of 'willRotateToInterfaceOrientation' and it worked smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Add constraint to 1st Button

1. Leading Space To NewView(gray colored)
2. Bottom space to NewView
3. Top Space to Topbutton (blue colored in your 1st and 2nd image)
4. Width (from Bottom - Right portion )[image]

Add Constraint to 2nd Button

1. Trailing Space to NEwView
2. Bottom space to NewView
3. Top Space to Topbutton (blue colored in your 1st and 2nd image)
4. Horizontal space FirstButton ( Search Community )
5. Width

Comment: Why should i redefine my constraints. they are working well. Problem comes when search community button has to be deleted. I can't figure out for which constraint i need to make iboutlet and give constant value so that  it comes out as shown in image second.

Comment: you mean you permanently want to delete Search comm. button or this will disable in some features?

Comment: yes permanently in the sense until user wants it so. As soon as user goes for option 'show search community', this screen should get back to its original form as shown in first image

Comment: Okay, so have tried with width constraint of Option button by changing constant and whenever you need to show again Search comm button then decrease constant value of Option button